# SQL server: complex left join query

Tags: sql-server, join

there are 2 tables:

```
people

+------------+--------------+------+
| name       | place        | pid  |
+------------+--------------+------+
| Mr John    | place1       |    1 |
| Miss Smith | place2       |    2 |
+------------+--------------+------+


places

+------+------+----------------------+
| pid  | owner| address              |
+------+------+----------------------+
|    1 |    1 | address1             |
|    1 | null | address2             |
|    2 | null | address3             |
|    2 | null | address4             |
|    2 | null | address5             |
+------+------+----------------------+
```

I am looking for a query which will return:

`people (complex left join) places on people.pid = places.pid`

```
Mr John    | place1 | 1 | 1 | 1    | address1
Miss Smith | place2 | 2 | 2 | null | address3
Miss Smith | place2 | 2 | 2 | null | address4
Miss Smith | place2 | 2 | 2 | null | address5
```

In words a join on `pid` but if there is a non null `owner` value for the specific `person` then get only that row, if there is not a non null `owner` value then get all the rows for the specific `person`. Using left join because I need also the `people` with `pid = null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT count(owner)over(partition by pid) mo,*
  FROM places
)
SELECT *
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN CTE
ON
  p.pid = CTE.pid
  and (mo = 0
       or owner is not null)
```

Answer (score 3):

One strategy is to pre process the `places` table in a CTE to identify which `pid` group of records have at least one non `NULL` owner value.  Such `pid` records need to all be included in the join.  On the other hand, if a `pid` group has at least one non `NULL` owner, then we will only include non `NULL` matches in the join.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT pid, owner, address,
        SUM(CASE WHEN owner IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
            (PARTITION BY pid) AS non_null_cnt
    FROM places
)

SELECT t1.name, t1.place, t1.pid, t2.owner, t2.address
FROM people t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.pid = t2.pid AND
       (t2.owner IS NOT NULL OR t2.non_null_cnt = 0)
ORDER BY t1.pid;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: For a strange reason Left Join doesnt work in my actual code, it acts like an inner join.... I updated the Demo adding my actual code

Comment: @atroul I can't speak to this, because my demo is at least working with your sample data.  If you can paste a demo link here which is failing, maybe I can have a look.

Comment: This will give the exact same result as my version